# How can I add a custom button the messenger page in BuddyBoss?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

[image][image]There is a hook in `buddyboss-platform/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/common/js-templates/messages/parts/bp-message-form.php:33` called `bp_nouveau_messages_hook( 'after', 'compose_content' );` which I want to access from my child theme in order to add some html. However, this hook doesn't behave like normal WordPress hooks and I cannot figure out how to access it.

Comment: Did you try bp_after_compose_content ?

Comment: If you mean like this:


`function tt_test() {
  echo '<h1>My custom text</h1>';
}

add_action('bp_after_compose_content ', 'tt_test' );`


than yes.

Comment: Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BP Nouveau template pack uses dynamic hooks.

```
bp_nouveau_messages_hook( 'after', 'compose_content' );
```

To use this hook you must include the component name ( *messages* ) between the stated pieces:

```
function test_nouveau_hook() {
    echo '<br>additional content here';
}
add_action( 'bp_after_messages_compose_content', 'test_nouveau_hook' );
```

Comment: @shanebp, are you available for consultation work?

Comment: Please contact me directly via my profile info.

Comment: @shanebp I didn't see any way to DM. Could you DM me if your interested?

Comment: There is no DM on stack, afaik.